# VBA - How to stop a sub with a key press, and resume again with another key press

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a sub in the Sheet object that, depending on which cell is being selected, requests either a number to be put in, or automatically references a different workbook and pastes a value from there. Let's say a wrong number was inputted, however. I am trying to create another process or sub that allows the user to select a cell to edit without having the automatic prompts or numbers popping up by pressing a key (lets say the esc key) to "pause" the other sub. Once the modifications are done, the user should be able to resume the "automatic sub" by pressing the same key again.

I looked into keypress and keydown actiivites, but I am only seeing methods that work once.

```
'some pseudocode to explain my method
'Working code that prompts or gets values depending on which cell is being selected
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   ...
End Sub

'Sub to allow for previous sub to paused/resumed
Sub
   'if esc is clicked, pause the selectionChange sub.
   'if esc is clicked again, resume the selctionChange sub.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Toggle to switch the functionality on and off.
The toggle can be called via a seperate macro call.

For example:

In the Worksheet Codebehind:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TSheet1
    autoEditOn As Boolean 'toggle
End Type
Private this As TSheet1

Public Property Get autoEditOn() As Boolean
    autoEditOn = this.autoEditOn
End Property
Public Property Let autoEditOn(value As Boolean)
    this.autoEditOn = value
End Property

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If autoEditOn Then doStuff ' only tun if toggle is true
End Sub


Private Sub doStuff()
    'Do something ' do  stuff in a seperate sub/function, keeps the code clean
End Sub
```

In a seperate Module called MacroHook:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub toggleAutoEdit() '<-- Call this function with a key-combo
    With Sheet1
        .autoEditOn = Not .autoEditOn
    End With
End Sub
```

There are other ways to do this, but I think this is one of the cleanest.

The private Type thing is explained here : [Private this as TSomething](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/)